# derivative of implicit function

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

supposed I have a function which is $q_2f_2(δq_1+q_2)$

I want to know the second derivative of the function w.r.t $q_2$
Firstly, I took the first derivative w.r.t to $q_2$ and I got the result as follow
$$q_2\frac{d(δq_1+q_2)}{dq_2}\frac{df_2(δq_1+q_2)}{d(δq_1+q_2)}+f_2(δq_1+q_2)$$

I tried to take second derivative and I got the following result.
$$q_2\frac{d}{dq_2}{(\frac{df_2(δq_1+q_2)}{d(δq_1+q_2)})}+\frac{df_2(δq_1+q_2)}{d(δq_1+q_2)}+\frac{d(δq_1+q_2)}{dq_2}\frac{df_2(δq_1+q_2)}{d(δq_1+q_2)}$$
I have a problem to solve the following part
$$ \frac{d}{dq_2}{(\frac{d f_2(δq_1+q_2)}{d(δq_1+q_2)})} $$
Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Is $f_2$ function of $q_2$?

Comment: See [How to write maths on Stack Exchange](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @AaronMaroja yes, $f_2$ is function of $\delta q_1$ and $q_2$

Comment: @DheerajKumar thanks a lot

Comment: Mhm${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial q_2}\Bigg(q_2f_2(\delta q_1 + q_2)\Bigg) = f_2(\delta q_1 + q_2) + q_2f_2'(\delta q_1 + q_2)\dot \ 1$$

Now for the second derivative

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial q_2}\Bigg(f_2(\delta q_1 + q_2) + q_2f_2'(\delta q_1 + q_2)\Bigg)$$

and again use the product and chain rule.

Comment: is it looks like the following equation ?

$$ \frac{d(\delta q_1 + q_2}{dq_2}\frac{df_2(\delta q_1 + q_2)}{d(\delta q_1 + q_2} + 1 \dot f_2^' (\delta q_1+q_2)+q_2 f_2^" $$

Comment: I can't read, you need to use $$ so I can see the latex.

Comment: I am really sorry.
This is what I mean. is that correct?

$$\frac{d(\delta q_1 + q_2)}{dq_2} \frac{df_2(\delta q_1 + q_2)}{d(\delta q_1 + q_2)} +1.f_2'(\delta q_1+q_2) + q_2 f_2''(\delta q_1+q_2)$$

Comment: Is $q_1$ also a variable? Notice that $\frac{d(\delta q_1 + q_2)}{dq_2} = 1$ and there is no $\frac{d}{d(\delta q_1 + q_2)}$.

Comment: Yes, it is also variable.
so, the result should be
$$1.f_2'(\delta q_1 + q_2)+1.f_2'(\delta q_1+q_2) + q_2 f_2''(\delta q_1+q_2)$$

is it correct ?

Comment: You're missing a $q_2$ on the second sum. Other than that is correct.

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean by missing a $q_2$ ?
The final result should be look like this, right? $$2f_2'(\delta q_1 + q_2) + q_2 f_2''(\delta q_1+q_2)$$

Comment: Yes, that's correct!